# Subtotal and Total in Power BI matrix

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am wroking on maxtrix visual and I need to deisplay Subtotal and Total into the visual. Its easy in SSRS but its not easy in Power BI desktop.

I am wroking on maxtrix visual and I need to deisplay Subtotal and Total into the visual. Its easy in SSRS but its not easy in Power BI desktop. Here is the output that I am looking for

| CusNumber | City | State | Zipcode | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 23 | 2 |
| 1 | b | c | 24 | 4 |
| Subtotal 1 |  |  |  | 6 |
| 2 | a | d | 55 | 1 |
| 2 | f | g | 55 | 2 |
| Subtotal 2 |  |  |  | 3 |
| 3 | g | f | 6 | 5 |
| 3 | fg | j | 67 | 6 |
| 3 | rfgh | f | 77 | 5 |
| Subtotal 3 |  |  |  | 16 |
| Total |  |  |  | 34 |

Comment: What does your Matrix currently look like? You should be able to achieve something similar to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xGMd.png